# Fully scalable website with micro-applications

Tags: rest, reactjs, redux, react-router, scalability

I'm in the process of designing a cloud deployed website for a new solution my company is looking to provide. I have been attempting to answer a few questions and haven't had any luck, so when in rome.

First, I don't want the website to be stuck to any one particular framework. I know there is no way to completely future proof a website, but I would rather not put all of our eggs in one basket.

Secondly, I want to have a separation between the front and back end entirely. I have a list of reasons why I'm looking to do this, don't necessarily want to get into the conversation of what they are. Server Side rendering for the most part is out of the question.

So where does that leave me?

My initial thoughts on the design are to have a REST API that can be accessed for any API calls (this may be turned to GraphQL in the future).

The design decisions that I'm mostly wresting with are for the front end. The website will be a dashboard type system, where tenants can log in and see screens for them.

I was thinking that I would have a sort of shell, that hooks on to the index.html. This would have it's own routing, that would render micro-applications that are completely separate from the shell logic.

So for example, if I load index.html, path being "/"

It has some routes that it's responsible for, lets say
"/todos"
"/account"

If I accessed the /todos route, my shell application would then render that micro app. This application would be completely separate from the shell, except some data that might be loaded via the window. Once this application is rendered via the shell application.

So my todos route, for example, could be a redux application that's independent. It could have it's own routing, etc.

Is this is a common architecture? Are there any examples of this? Is there a better way of going about this?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your well and truly over engineering this beast.

You may take on such an architecture for a HUGE build with many dev teams all working separately. Small agile team,  the above would create so much overhead in boilerplate and brain ache in context switching between each "app"

Micro-service architecture is seriously great. Just don't break it up too small, read your use case well and break your services up accordingly.

For example: we are a team of 3. We have a pretty large-ish app devised into:

1. Php API
2. Backend management interface (redux)
3. Frontend website (html, react, php)
4. Search service (elastic search)
5. Cache (redis)
6. Data store (mysql)

All on running in multiple docker containers across multiple hosts. Pull down the backend.. Fine the frontend website is still up and running!

Comment: Appreciate your insight. I think I was getting ahead of myself while thinking about feathering in micro-apps in the future that may not be the same framework.

Comment: If you future proof that much, the future will never arrive ;-)